# What sort of content does SuperUser want? What is a "useful" contribution?

Tags: discussion, answers, deleted-answer

I tried to contribute on Super User, by:

1. Answering "yes" (with an explanation as to why) to a yes/no question
2. Commenting on an UNSOLVED issue, that has been idle and open for about 2 years now.

Every "contribution" I made was deleted, detailing, that what I wrote was useless.

[Do I need to wait for 100% resync?](https://superuser.com/questions/1412880/do-i-need-to-wait-for-100-resync/1602188#1602188)

> Please do not submit commentary as an answer. It doesn’t appear this answer is an actual solution to the author’s problem – Ramhound 13 hours ago

It is about a RAID setup that will never stop resyncing, a widespread problem among Windows setups. I posted one actual reason for it, so this MIGHT BE an answer to some users having this problem. it was explicitly *not* for Windows 10, but for a big number of other Windows versions (so maybe related? the VSS subsystem exists in Windows 10, too!)

> > This post is hidden. It was deleted 12 hours ago by Ramhound, DavidPostill♦.
> >
> > ... Asked 1 year, 8 months ago Active 3 months ago Viewed 3k times
>
> still no answer to this issue.
>
> same problem here (windows10). resyncing was triggered out of thin air and it will never finish.
> I noticed a lot of disk activity in task manager for no apparent reason.
> The System so busy resyncing my game-framerate drops.
>
> ...trying to put one device "offline" using the disk manager and putting it online again but for 8TB RAID1 every step takes forever.
>
> i found this about "volsnap.sys": Applies to: Win7 Ent, Pro, Ult,Windows Server 2008 R2(...) https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/2913050/mirrored-raid-volumes-report-resynching-status-after-you-restart-windo

I have tried using the comment section in order to narrow down the problem and actively *find* a solution.

**My Question is:** What does this site want, content-wise? having answers does imply finding solutions to a problem. Do you really want to strip questions and answers from the process of finding a solution?

Comment: Maybe I’m just stupid or dense (although I believe that I’m not), but I cannot understand the last sentence of your question: “Do you really want to strip questions and answers from the process of finding a solution?” At Super User, we believe “give a man a fish and you feed him for a day; teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime” — in other words, it’s better to teach questioners how to solve their problems than it is to simply give them solutions.  Does that address your question?

Answer (score 1):

I hope you’re serious about wanting guidance.

- The question is about a resync that the OP predicts will take 11 hours. 
  The OP asks “Can I safely shut down my computer
  and will it continue the process after next boot?”

  You *say* that the question is about a RAID setup
  that will never stop resyncing. 
  (Where do you see that?) 
  You answer says it will "resync" forever and NEVER finish. 
  That’s just a restatement of your misunderstanding of the question! 
  What question do you believe that you are answering?
- Imagine that you go into a library and say
  “I have a question about potato waffles.” 
  The librarian gets out a piece of paper, scribbles something on it,
  hands it to you and says “Here’s the address of somebody who can help you.” 
  You say “I thought the library was supposed to have all the information.” 
  The librarian says “I knew the address, didn’t I?”

  Similarly, some of us believe that Super User should have information. 
  Some of us believe that posts that say
  “Here’s the address of a site that has the answer” are not useful. 
  You should copy the information,
  and include the link for reference and attribution. 
  So that’s what Ramhound meant when they said that a link to a solution
  does not qualify as an answer.

  Oh, but first check the site that contains the solution
  for their copying policy. 
  If they don’t allow copying of their information,
  you probably shouldn’t do it. 
  Post the link ***in a comment**.*
- Your first answer said “i [sic] am going to try this procedure here
  and report back once its [sic] done.” 
  How do you believe that to be useful? 
  If you have discovered a procedure that might work,
  try it ***first*** and *then* post an answer.
  <sup>[OK, I see that Ramhound already said some of the above.]</sup>
- Ramhound said “You also resubmitted the same answer,
  after it was originally deleted by a moderator, that isn't allowed.” 
  I’ll admit that that might not be obvious to a new user. 
  For future reference, here’s what to do if your answer gets deleted.

  1. Try very hard to figure out why it was deleted. 
     Often somebody will leave a comment. 
     Unfortunately, that doesn’t seem to have happened in this case.

     - If you can’t figure it out, you can post a question here on Meta. 
       But, if you do this more than twice per decade,
       people will regard you as a pest
       and somebody might delete your account (or at least suspend it).

     When you understand why the answer was deleted,
  2. Edit it to fix the problem(s), and
  3. Flag it, and ask for it to be undeleted.
- Copying the “Asked *<when>* ago  Active *<when>* ago  
  Viewed *<how many>* times” header into an answer
  is something people frequently do by accident
  (when they’re going on a wild copy&paste spree,
  which they probably shouldn’t be doing). 
  Please don’t do that — especially not on purpose.

Comment: If you quote and cite a source, you will be hard pressed to find any website, that doesn’t allow you to quote and cite it. That’s the entire point of quoting and citing the source.

Comment: @dafriet - At no point do you address the author’s question, only your own problem, indicating facts that were never mentioned in the question.  If you believe a comment isn’t helpful just delete it.  **You never specifically actually indicated if the author can safely reboot their system.**.

Comment: @ramhound oh i have edited that post about the software raid failed and missing. but the system said that it cannot be undeleted. too bad it contains step-by-step information with the correct information on the specific issue.

Comment: @ramhound my last comment was on https://superuser.com/questions/1594658/software-raid-failed-and-missing/1602259#1602259 
you mean the other part about the 11hrs and the reboot. i got that when you mentioned it the first time, i got it when scott repeated it... is there a reason you are putting it a third time on the plate?

Comment: @Ramhound: I threw that in because I just a few hours ago stumbled across [this](http://web.archive.org/web/20080514205739/http://www.math.wustl.edu/%7Emsh210/legal.html#c): “No, you may not mirror, cache, archive, or copy anything I write or say on the Internet, whether on the World-Wide Web, on Usenet, via e-mail, or otherwise.”  I don’t know whether I should take it seriously (especially since it’s not publicly viewable live; only on the Wayback Machine).   But, OTOH, I believe that I have seen similar claims / warnings elsewhere.  (E.g., maybe on the Oxford Dictionary, which is paywalled.)

Comment: @dafriet - You edited that answer, 45 minutes ago, when I made my comment about your answer it was a single sentence.  You edited an answer to a entirely different question than you have asked about.

Comment: @ramhound if there is such a disclaimer and i missed that, then please go on and delete it. i do not want to cause trouble. but if you say it was only on WBM, then we have to take it as a given that he changed his mind.

Comment: @ramhound yes, i edited the answer because the initial claim was that it was unrelated to the question, which was true. you asked me to edit it. i didnt know that i should have given another answer and flagged the old one as "unfixable by editing."(or sth like that, its described in the flags)

Comment: @dafriet - No; Editing the answer was exactly what you should have done.  However, I wanted to make it clear, when I submitted my answer to that now deleted answer it was a single sentence.

Comment: @ramhound got it. now should i repost this as an answer or can you undelete it? 
i am pretty sure my answer does not 100% anwer the question but at least it answers a portion of it so it's not useless.

Comment: @dafriet - You should edit the (deleted) answer so it answers 100% of the question.  However, the answer you [edited](https://superuser.com/questions/1594658/software-raid-failed-and-missing/1602259#1602259), was for an entirely different question.  The two answers to the linked question, you are specifically asking about, are not actual answers but commentary (nor have they been edited). When you refer to an answer as a comment, it's probably going to be deleted as a comment, for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 0):

> It is about a RAID setup that will never stop resyncing, a widespread problem among Windows setups. I posted one actual reason for it, so this MIGHT BE an answer to some users having this problem. it was explicitly not for Windows 10, but for a big number of other Windows versions (so maybe related? the VSS subsystem exists in Windows 10, too!)

While it certainly can be appropriate for answers to be possible solutions, they must also contain that possible solution, answers that are not written in a way that makes the solution clear will be mistaken for commentary.

In this case, your answer was written in a way, that confirmed the issue still existed.  We already knew that was the case, a working solution to the question had yet not been submitted.  Indicating the problem still exists, in an answer, is necessary and was treated as commentary.

Your answer only had two possible solutions contained within it.  The first indicated that putting the drive offline and online took forever.  You don't indicate if this actually resolves the resyncing problem, when I voted to delete your answer, I took that as commentary.

> ...trying to put one device "offline" using the disk manager and putting it online again but for 8TB RAID1, every step takes forever.

The only other part of your answer that could be taken as a solution reference an external link.  I read the external link and didn't actually see a solution there.  If there was a solution that existed on the page it certainly wasn't clear.

> i found this about "volsnap.sys": Applies to: Win7 Ent, Pro, Ult, Windows Server 2008 R2(...) https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/2913050/mirrored-raid-volumes-report-resynching-status-after-you-restart-windo

You didn't quote the relevant information from this link, you just reference a link, which I again took as commentary.  So in the end you indicate the problem still exists (commentary), you indicated that taking the drive offline and putting it online again takes forever (commentary), and you make reference to a link that doesn't contain a solution to the problem.

Answers are supposed to indicate what the solution to the problem is.  We are not a forum, having a discussion about a problem is not allowed, it certainly isn't allowed when you submit answers to have that discussion.  As for your other answer, it also was deleted, since it was commentary.

> I am going to try this procedure here and report back once it's done. https://christitus.com/windows-software-raid/

If you have a possible solution, wait until you have tried the solution, then submit a detailed answer on how to solve the problem using that solution.  Indicating you have a possible solution and are going to try it, is not helpful to the community.  **I have had my share of problems that I have had to solve, nothing is more frustrating to find a discussion about a problem, only to run into a comment like "I will report back once it's done" only to realize it's from years ago.**

Answer (score 0):

> What does this site want, content-wise?

See [What topics can I ask about here?](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic).

> Do you really want to strip questions and answers from the process of
> finding a solution?

The answer to your second question is likely to be opinion-based, I believe.
To the best of my understanding, this is fine for the meta section of
a site, such as this https://meta.superuser.com.

I strive at writing answers in a way that makes the reader understand
the solution to the question as quickly as possible. In 99 cases out of 100,
this will most likely mean "to strip questions and answers from the process
of finding a solution".

Thus, my answer to your second question is: ***Yes***!

References:
https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask
https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/625553

Comment: thank you for this answer. as i am new to this platform, i cannot upvote answers but i still did. 
finding a solution is a mess and tends to generate data that is useless or even misleading, so removing that part does make sense in a way even if you cannot know how the solution was actually found.
it may even be subject do NDA, which i absolutely did not think about at all.

Comment: @dafriet, thanks for your attempt to upvote. :-) - I never considered confidentiality an issue from my perspective. And I certainly don't mean to imply that the _process_ of finding a solution is unimportant or uninteresting. On the contrary! But I think it would often become a problem to include such a description in an answer - it would risk becoming a "TL;DR" kind of answer. . . . I am fairly new myself to _actively_ contributing to these [stackexchange sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#), starting in Sep 2019. But before that I had been reading stackoverflow for about six years. (!)